# How to strip HTML tags from div content using Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had made one `div` tag and stored its contents in a variable. If this tag contains `p,b` or any other tags then it should be removed from string. How can I achieve this?

Comment: add a jsfiddle to show us some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use the regular expression.

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
var body = "<p>test</p>"
var result = body.replace(regex, "");

alert(result);
```

**HERE IS THE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/Efu4f/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution breaks for this valid string: `"<img alt=\"a>b\" src=\"a_b.gif\" />"`

Comment: Check bellow http://stackoverflow.com/a/43087700/2012407 for additional info and larger coverage.

Comment: The solution is perfect

Answer (score 8):

You can follow this example

```
var stringContent = "<p>Hi dear</p><p>Wish you a happy birthday</p>";

var text = $(stringContent).text();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is safer:

```
function plaintext(html){
  return $("<div/>").html(html).text();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to add a few things **on top of the accepted answer** which is suggesting the regex `var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig`:

- you don't need the `i` flag in your regex as you don't match any alphabetic character. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/66L6nfwt/2/
- you don't need any pair of brackets as you just replace with nothing the whole match. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/66L6nfwt/3/
- This regex can be improved as it will fail if you use both chars `<` and `>` in your text content. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/66L6nfwt/4/
- So here is a regex improvement: `/<\/?\w+[^>]*\/?>/g`. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/66L6nfwt/5/

---

**Final code:**

```
var regex = /<\/?\w+[^>]*\/?>/g,
    body = "<sTrong><b>test<b></STRONG><b> sss</b><em> what if you write some maths: i < 2 && i > 4.</em>";

alert(body.replace(regex, ""));
```

> It can also be helpful to place the function in the built-in 'String' class so you can do this directly :
>
> > `"<em>test</em>".stripTags()`

```
String.prototype.stripTags = function()
{
    return this.replace(/<\/?\w+[^>]*\/?>/g, '');
};
```

---

**Eventually, if your string is a DOM node, you can do `alert(element.innerText || element.textContent);` which is built-in and even safer!** See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/66L6nfwt/6/

Answer (score 1):

Using plain javascript you can do it as

```
string.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
```

I think this is probably faster than the .text() method.

Answer (score 0):

Solution Using JQuery:

```
var content = "<p>Dear Andy,</p><p>This is a test message.</p>";

var text = $(content).text();
```

Solution using JavaScript:

```
function removeTags(){
    var txt = document.getElementById('myString').value;
    var rex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
    alert(txt.replace(rex , ""));

}
```

Also look a this link:
[Strip HTML Tags in JavaScript](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/strip-html-tags-in-javascript/)