# JQuery word count and stripping tags from HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do a word-count of a textarea that accepts HTML input.

My first step is to strip tags from the input. I have found this code from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript):

```
$("<div></div>").html(html).text();
```

Which works great, but is vulnerable to script tags in the html:

```
html = "<script>alert()";
```

I am trying to mitigate this by using:

```
$("<p>").html(html).remove('script').text();
```

Which successfully handles the example above. Unfortunately it doesn't handle:

```
html = "<script><script>alert();</script>";
```

As it only removes the outer script.

I'm trying to write a while loop to continually remove scripts until there are none left to remove, but I'm struggling with the logic.

I want something like this:

```
var $div = $("<div></div>").html(html);
while(*remove script causes a change*){
  $div = $div.remove('script');
}
text = $div.text();
```

Is this possible? And is this safe?

Is there any way to handle `onXXX=""` attributes in other elements too?

Comment: "Is this safe?" rolling your own HTML sanitization? no, not at all. Use a whitelist that's been tested thoroughly. You've completely missed things like `<img src="nonexistant" onerror="...malicious code...">`.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks, yep, I added that to the question.. any idea where I'd find such a whitelist?

Comment: that's an off-topic question. Use google.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regular expression:

```
var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
var body = "<p>test</p>"
var result = body.replace(regex, "");

alert(result);
```

Found an another answer on StackOverflow:
[How to strip HTML tags from div content using Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398635/how-to-strip-html-tags-from-div-content-using-javascript-jquery)

Please sanitize the string before saving into the database.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't handle certain valid strings and I'd rather not use regex if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

I settled on using the [phpjs](http://phpjs.org/about/) version of the php function [strip_tags](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags/), which appears to be working nicely and handling script tags well.

My simplistic word count function so far is:

```
$('#input').on('input',function(){
    var text = $(this).val();
    text = strip_tags(text).replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
    var wordCount = 0;
    if(text != ''){
      var words = text.split(' ');
      wordCount = words.length;
    }

    $('#word-count').html(wordCount);
});
```